# Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': Index (zero based)

Tags: deployment, error, solution-package

Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument.

Getting this error on deployment both from CA and VS. Any ideas on what might cause this?

**More detailed exception:**

System.FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.
 at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormat(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)
 at System.String.Format(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSolutionLanguagePack.EnsureSolutionPackage()
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSolutionLanguagePack.DeployLocalCore(Boolean globalInstallWPPackDlls, Collection`1 webApplications, Boolean useAdminService, Boolean force, Boolean checkIfDeployed)

 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSolutionLanguagePack.DeployLocal(Boolean globalInstallWPPackDlls, Collection`1 webApplications, Boolean force)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.SolutionPageBase.CreateDeploymentJob(Boolean deploy, String strSelectedWeb, Boolean globalInstall, DateTime dt, Boolean localDeployment)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.DeploySolutionPage.BtnSubmit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
 at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
 at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
 at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Comment: Does this occur with any wsp file?

Comment: It only occurs with one WSP file.

Comment: then, you should check your manifest.xml which is inside wsp. probably comparing manifest.xml with one from a working wsp will help to spot some property which is missing or corrupted or smth like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was fixed by ensuring that all solution dependencies were deployed. The exception is thrown when SharePoint tries to resolve the resource file for the error message that dependencies are missing. Probably a bug or maybe an update gone wrong with resource files in SharePoint.

Statement that fails in SharePoint:

string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, SPResource.GetString("ActivationSolutionDependencyXXXX", new object[0]), new object[0]);